# Non-dimensionalise

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

A body of constant mass is thrown vertically upwards from the ground. It can be shown that the appropriate non-dimensional differential equation for the height $x(t;u)$, reached at time $t\geq0$ is given by
\begin{equation} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -1-\mu (\frac{dx}{dt})
\end{equation}
with corresponding initial conditions $x(0)=0, \frac{dx}{dt}(0) =1$, and where $0<\mu<<1.$
Deduce that the (non-dimensional) height at the highest point (where $\frac{dx}{dt} =0$) is given by
\begin{equation} h(\mu)= \frac{1}{\mu}- \frac{1}{\mu^2} log_e(1+\mu) \end{equation}

=>
It really hard for me to start

I was thinking do integration twice by doing the separation of variable:
\begin{equation} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -1-\mu (\frac{dx}{dt})
\end{equation}
I got the general solution of \begin{equation}x(t)= \frac{log(t\mu +1) -t \mu}{\mu^2}\end{equation}

after that I do not know how to get the answer. 
Please help me.

Comment: Take the derivative of $x$ and set it equal to $0$. That will tell you where the height is at a max. Side note: do you know why that equation works?! The left is acceleration, undimensional version of Force. The right side is also force (hence the equality!): a -1 for downward gravity (undimensional, not the usual 9.8) and a $cx'$ for wind resistance (typically taken to be proportional to speed, some $\text{constant}\times(\text{velocity or x'(t)})$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -1-\mu \left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right), x(0)=0, x'(0)= 1$$

Solving the homogeneous solution we have:

$$x_h(t) = c_1 + c_2 e^{-\mu t}$$

Solving for the particular solution (choose $x_p(t) = a t$) and solve for the constant $a$, yielding:

$$x_p(t) = -\dfrac{t}{\mu}$$

Using the initial conditions to solve for the constants, we arrive at:

$$x(t) = \dfrac{ \left((-t \mu+\mu+1)-e^{-t \mu}(\mu+1)\right)}{\mu^2}$$

We now want to find the maximum height. To do this, we have to solve $x'(t) = 0$ to find $t$ and then substitute that into $x(t)$. We have:

$$x'(t) = \dfrac{e^{-t \mu} \left(-e^{t \mu}+\mu+1\right)}{\mu} = 0 \rightarrow t = \dfrac{\log_e(1+\mu)}{\mu}$$

Substituting this $t$ into $x(t)$ yields the max height of:

$$h(\mu) = \dfrac{\mu-\log_e (\mu+1)}{\mu^2} = \dfrac{1}{\mu} - \dfrac{\log_e(1+\mu)}{\mu ^2}$$

Comment: Excellent "process" model!